# Does HTTPie have the equivalent of curl's -d option?

Tags: rest, curl, httpie

I want to query a REST API with HTTPie. I am usuale to do so with curl, with which I am able to specify `maxKeys` and `startAfterFilename` e.g.

```
curl --location --request GET -G \                                                                                                  
"https://some.thing.some.where/data/v1/datasets/mydataset/versions/2/files" \
-d maxKeys=100 \
-d startAfterFilename=YYYMMDD_HHMMSS.file \
--header "Authorization: verylongtoken"
```

How can I use those `-d` options in HTTPie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the command looks like this:

```
http -F https://some.thing.some.where/data/v1/datasets/mydataset/versions/2/files \
    Authorization:verylongtoken \
    startAfterFilename=="YYYMMDD_HHMMSS.file" \
    maxKeys=="100"
```

Although, there is a bunch of methods to pass some data with `httpie`. For example

```
http POST http://example.com/posts/3 \
    Origin:example.com \  # :   HTTP headers
    name="John Doe" \     # =   string
    q=="search" \         # ==  URL parameters (?q=search)
    age:=29 \             # :=  for non-strings
    list:='[1,3,4]' \     # :=  json
    file@file.bin \       # @   attach file
    token=@token.txt \    # =@  read from file (text)
    user:=@user.json      # :=@ read from file (json)
```

Or, in the case of forms

```
http --form POST example.com \
    name="John Smith" \
    cv=@document.txt
```